# Custom progress bar in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a .gif file I'd like to use instead of basic `withProgress` bar, but I see no straightforward way to use it.

So, the question is – how do I create a custom progress bar? Couldn't figure out if I can use `Progress` for this task.

edit: with some css (though I'm no css-wizard) I got it to somewhat work, but the first time the progress bar appears - image is shown late, when the `withProgress` is almost done. The text message provided to `withProgress` shows as needed.

css file sourced in UI:

```
.shiny-progress-container{
    padding-top:10%;
    top: -5px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: transparent!important;
    text-align: center;
    color:black;
}
.shiny-progress-container .progress-text{
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center!important;
}
.shiny-progress-container .progress-text .progress-message{
    background-image: url(loading.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 140px;
    background-position: 50% -0;
    padding-top: 150px;
    width: 400px;
}
.shiny-progress-container .shiny-progress:first-child .progress-text {
    background-image: url(loading.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 140px;
    background-position: 50% -0;
    padding-top: 150px;
    width: 400px;
}

.shiny-progress-container .shiny-progress:last-child  .progress-text {
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: There is an R package specifically for that purpose: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinycustomloader/shinycustomloader.pdf

Comment: Hi @GregordeCillia, nice package. As I understand, it works on ui side only? I have some heavy calculations happening on the server in observers, not sure if I can apply that package to it.

Comment: I didn't test that package but the way I see it, you can "attach" the gif to an output id and the gif will be shown whenever the corresponding output is invalidated (out of sync with the inputs). It does not really matter how the output is calculated. That said, `renderUI` might be troublesome when combined with this package.

Comment: I see. I tried to utilize it for my purposes - but it seems that it works only with UI elements (e.g. plot gets invalidated), while I'd prefer a solution that will work on server side, too (as `withProgress` does). Thank you for sharing anyways.